# Get values from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array like:

```
var someArray = [{"id":1,"mid":"477","mname":"StackOverflow","image":"images/merchants/so.jpg"}, {"id":2,"mid":"478","mname":"Meta","image":"images/merchants/mt.jpg"}]
```

How do I get say the image string `images/merchants/so.jpg` for example?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy not exactly. The main array in that one has keys. This one does not.

Comment: this should work `someArray[0].image`

Comment: @D-Day the question is extremely similar and the answers there should explain how to access objects like these -- the question I linked to was meant to address these types of questions in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
someArray[0].image
or
someArray[0]['image']
```

Comment: I get `undefined` with either method. So that's why I had to ask the question.